# Google Maps loadGeoJson function not working clickable

Tags: google-maps

Loadgeojson clickable not working.
how can i make it work?

```
map.data.setStyle({
    clickable: false
});

map.data.loadGeoJson(permits, null, function () {
                // create empty bounds object
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                // loop through features
                map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
                    var geo = feature.getGeometry();
          
                    geo.forEachLatLng(function (LatLng) {
                        bounds.extend(LatLng);
                      
                    });
                });
                // fit data to bounds
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                map.setZoom(18);
         
              
            });
           

            var Fay =  "/" + "Faylar.json";
            var faylar = Fay;
          
            map.data.loadGeoJson(faylar, null, function () {
                // create empty bounds object
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                // loop through features
                map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
                  
                    var geo = feature.getGeometry();
                    geo.forEachLatLng(function (LatLng) {
                        bounds.extend(LatLng);

                    });
                });
                // fit data to bounds
               
              
            });

            map.data.setStyle({
                fillColor: "green",
                strokeWeight: 1,
                clickable: true
            });
```

Hi, Loadgeojson clickable not working.

how can i make it work?
How do I properly trigger this event using the loadGeoJson layer only?
What is the exact method to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your GeoJSON look like?  What do you expect to happen when you click on the GeoJSON? [Event handler example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event)

Comment: geojson file is a geometry field. I want to add a marker inside the geometry area when clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a "click" event to the data layer:

```
  map.data.addListener("click", (event) => {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: event.latLng.toUrlValue(3),
      map: map
    })
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o754a3rh/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let marker;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: -28, lng: 137 },
  });
  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json",
  );
  // Add some style.
  map.data.setStyle((feature) => {
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty("color"),
      strokeWeight: 1,
    };
  });
  map.data.addListener("click", (event) => {
    if (marker) marker.setMap(null);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: event.latLng.toUrlValue(3),
      map: map
    })
  })
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#info-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Layer: Event Handling</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="info-box">?</div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises.
      See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```